# Best practice for potentially large amount of data in single table SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with three columns: user_id, post_id and voting.
Each post in the application can get a voting by multiple users but only one voting per user.

Imagine we end up with 1 billion posts and an average of 1000 votings on each. Would it still be a good practice to store all these information in a single table? (performancewise)
Is it maybe better to split the information in different tables, maybe userwise? (potentially multiple thousand users, so multiple tables)

Comment: A billion records in a well designed and indexed table should be workable, a trillion records is another story.  If you really have massive data then maybe look into periodically archiving.

Comment: I guess with only those 3 fields a [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html) on date ranges isn't an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best practices create a [non-clustered index](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9133/sql-server-non-clustered-indexes/) on user_id the reason I say this is it will help you to run operations like - get all posts of a particular user etc.

If in future record is very big like half to what you mentioned you can do DB shading it will improve overall performance. The idea is to distribute data that can’t fit on a single node onto a cluster of database nodes. You can refer to your vendor's documentation to achieve these.

Comment: Postgres doesn't have clustered indexes, so a "non-clustered" one is the only one, Zyan can create. Why link to SQL Server tips when the question is about Postgres?